# How to change the date format of the whole column?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I am analyzing the .csv file and in this my first column is of the datetime in the format "2016-09-15T00:00:13" and I want to change this format to standard python datetime object.I can change the format for one but date but for whole column I can not do that.

My code that I am using:

```
import numpy
import dateutil.parser
mydate = dateutil.parser.parse(numpy.mydata[1:,0])
print(mydate)
```

I am getting the error:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'mydata'

Here is the column for which I want the format to be changed.

```
print(mydata[1:,0])

['2016-09-15T00:00:13' 

'2016-09-15T00:00:38' 

'2016-09-15T00:00:53' 

...,

'2016-09-15T23:59:28' 

'2016-09-15T23:59:37' 

'2016-09-15T23:59:52']
```

Comment: Did you try using `pandas` data-frames?

Comment: Look into making the column `np.datetime64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

for date in mydata:
  date_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Here's [a link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to the method I'm using. That same link also lists the format arguments.

Oh and about the

> 'module' object has no attribute 'mydata'

You call `numpy.mydata` which is a reference to the "mydata" attribute of the numpy module you imported. The problem is, is that "mydata" is just one of your variables, not something included with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a compelling reason to avoid it, pandas is the way to go with this kind of analysis. You can simply do

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=True)
```

This will assume the first column is the index column and parse dates in it. This is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've dealt with that `numpy.mydata[1:,0]` attribute error

Your data looks like:

```
In [268]: mydata=['2016-09-15T00:00:13' ,
     ...: '2016-09-15T00:00:38' ,
     ...: '2016-09-15T00:00:53' ,
     ...: '2016-09-15T23:59:28' ,
     ...: '2016-09-15T23:59:37' ,
     ...: '2016-09-15T23:59:52']
```

or in array form it is a ld array of strings

```
In [269]: mydata=np.array(mydata)
In [270]: mydata
Out[270]: 
array(['2016-09-15T00:00:13', '2016-09-15T00:00:38', '2016-09-15T00:00:53',
       '2016-09-15T23:59:28', '2016-09-15T23:59:37', '2016-09-15T23:59:52'], 
      dtype='<U19')
```

`numpy` has a version of `datetime` that stores as a 64 bit float, and can be used numerically.  Your dates readily convert to that with `astype` (your format is standard):

```
In [271]: mydata.astype(np.datetime64)
Out[271]: 
array(['2016-09-15T00:00:13', '2016-09-15T00:00:38', '2016-09-15T00:00:53',
       '2016-09-15T23:59:28', '2016-09-15T23:59:37', '2016-09-15T23:59:52'], 
       dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

`tolist` converts this array to a list - and the dates to `datetime` objects:

```
In [274]: D.tolist()
Out[274]: 
[datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0, 13),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0, 53),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 23, 59, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 23, 59, 37),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 23, 59, 52)]
```

which could be turned back into an array of dtype object:

```
In [275]: np.array(D.tolist())
Out[275]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0, 13),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0, 38),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 0, 0, 53),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 23, 59, 28),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 23, 59, 37),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 15, 23, 59, 52)], dtype=object)
```

These objects couldn't be used in array calculations.  The list would be just as useful.

If your string format wasn't standard you'd have to use the `datetime` parser in a list comprehension as `@staples` shows.